# When I refresh my page To do list Elements of To do list Disappear I want that my Elements of To do list does not Disappear

Tags: function, validation, refresh, reload, todoist

When I refresh my page To do list Elements of To do list Disappear I want any easiest methode that If I refresh or reload our page my to do list data dont Disappear

When I refresh my page To do list Elements of To do list Disappear I want any easiest methode that If I refresh or reload our page my to do list data dont Disappear

Comment: Can you show us the code or a minimum reproducable product? Also, please don't repeat the same sentence 3 times - give us an overview in the title and non repetitive paragraphs in the description.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.